# Could someone please identify this species?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I have come across these insects a lot more lately, as far as I can tell, they can sustain a hover state in flight. I'm actually quite interested to know what these are, seeing they look like a cross between a bumblebee and a common housefly...

[image: What species is this...?]

Comment: For species ID questions, it is very useful to know where and when you saw the animal, and it can be useful to know details such as weather conditions. Could you provide some of these extra details?

Comment: Easily done, lower Blue Mountains, Bew South Wales in Australia, about 4pm AEST, overcast conditions...

Comment: Based on location, behaviour, and markings, I'd go with some sort of hoverfly (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoverfly). I can't offer positive ID, but I would hazard a guess at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melangyna_viridiceps based on the all-black thorax and the fact that this species is relatively common.

Comment: New South Wales*

Comment: It's definitely a hoverfly (Syrphidae), but I don't you will get a certain identification to the species level based on that single photograph.

Comment: @bshane, in the few pics I've seen, Melangyna stands with the wings folded, while Eupeodes stands with the wings spread apart. But don't know if this is a useful taxonomic trait for that group.

Answer (score 1):

Looks very similar to Eupeodes corollae (Syrphidae). But only a specialist in the group will tell you if its the same species, genus or family. And not with that low-resolution photograph (sometimes they need to take the genitals off for proper identification).

Comment: the photo was the best I could I at short notice... I'll see if I can update the photo at a later time.

Comment: Better talk to a specialist. Depending on the group, you can only know the species by capturing an individual. And sometimes, only knowing the place and the flower it's in, is enough for the identification.